# Google Tag Manager - push events not working after initial load

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Implemented Google Tag Manager on our application and initial page load works fine as shown in the below image of Tag Assistant.

[image]

Now after what seems to be 3 seconds, no further pushes onto the dataLayer variable are being tracked.

My initial dataLayer and Tag Manager code in the header.

```
<script>dataLayer = [];</script>
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-####" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src= '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-######');</script>
```

Here is the debug code for the 'timed#' events.

```
var count = 1;

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(count);

    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'timed' + count,
        'test': count
    });

    count++;
}, 5000);
```

This is looping continuously as expected in the console, but it only seems to add one of the events to Tag Manager.

Had a search of various documentation and other issues but can only find cases where it doesn't work at all. While this seems to only work for the initial capture.

Is there some setting which might have been missed?

Comment: How did you define this variable? Is it with a custom HTML tag to fire on all pages? There's nothing wrong with the code and I can implement this on my test site (as a custom HTML tag).

Comment: I have included the very basic setup code as copied from Tag Manager guides.

Comment: Mmm... I don't like how you have `dataLayer = []` in the header. Why do you have that there? Doing this can break the GTM dataLayer in unexpected ways. Try implementing GTM without altering ANY code.

Comment: Tried removing that whole line, still the same issue.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your tag with the code, and also the trigger?

Comment: The GTM code? Not sure I follow (been a long day haha)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126748/discussion-between-nyuen-and-nick).

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you have a custom HTML tag, and the contents is as provided, then all you need to do is to add a  around your function:

```
<script>
var count = 1;

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(count);

    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'timed' + count,
        'test': count
    });

    count++;
}, 5000);

</script>
```

I tested it and with the script it fires as you are expecting it to. This is because it is a custom HTML tag, not a Javascript tag so you need to declare that the contents is Javascript.

Comment: I excluded that from mine for simplicity in the question. The code is firing as it logs to the console...

Comment: Are you using the GTM debugger?

Comment: I use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en

Comment: Try using the GTM debugger through pressing Preview (under publish). From memory the tag assistant takes a static snapshot.